# BackHandler.removeEventListener is not wotking in react-native for android

Tags: react-native

Cannot get BackHandler.removeEventListener to work. Can anyone please guide as of how to use it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.backHandler.remove();
}
```

Comment: @rajeshvinew Your contribution is rendered unclear by the too strong use of an unknown (at least to me) syntax. Would you like to elaborate your meaning?

Comment: Thank you , I had been trying to solve back handler issue for days and finally thanks to your answer, solved it.

Answer (score 8):

**An update on how to do it with **hooks**** -
I finally made it working by keeping the function we are passing in BackHandler.addEventListener inside useEffect only and with it by using isFocused method of navigation. Any change in the following code breaks it -

```
useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
        if (navigation.isFocused()) {
            Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to exit the app?", [
                {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    onPress: () => null,
                    style: "cancel"
                },
                { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
            ]);
            return true;
        }

    };
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
    return () => backHandler.remove();
}, [])
```

This is my second answer, if it helps please mark this as useful.

Answer (score 6):

I used it in functional component :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const backhandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
        return true;
    });
    return () => {
        backhandler.remove();
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: This works perfectly on functional components. 

Answer (score 4):

This is also quite same answer, but safe handling added.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.backHandler = null;
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.backHandler)
          this.backHandler.remove();
        this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('backPress', this.handleBackButton.bind(this));
      }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.backHandler)
          this.backHandler.remove();
      }

    handleBackButton() {
        return true;
      }
```

Comment: Your code is not working correctly. Removing if statement from componentDidMount doing the job. `componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      this.backAction.bind(this)
    );
  } `

Answer (score 3):

import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native'

const isFocused = useIsFocused()

const myCallback = () => {

console.log("myCallback is running...")

}

```
useEffect(() => {

    if (isFocused) {
        BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", myCallback)
    }

    return () => {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", myCallback)
    }

}, [isFocused])
```

Comment: The only that worked for me in stack navigator

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue a lot.If we use **addEventListener & removeEventListener**, it will **removeEventListener** only when we reset/navigate to other stacks.

Suppose we want to restrict the back option on initial page:

Stack:

->screen1(we should prevent back option here and also we pass props to screen2)

->screen2(it will send some results to screen1)

->other screens ...

In that case **removeEventListener** is not working.

So, i have solved this issue on **getStateForAction**.This it the following code i have used.

```
const defaultGetStateForAction = PrimaryNavigation.router.getStateForAction;
PrimaryNavigation.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    const screen = state ? state.routes[state.index] : null;
    if (
      action.type === NavigationActions.BACK &&
      screen &&
      (screen.routeName === "Register" ||
        screen.routeName === "OwnerDashboard" ||
        screen.routeName === "LandingPage" ||
        screen.routeName === "OptionPage" ||
        (screen.routeName === "loginStack" && screen.index == 0) 
        || (screen.routeName === "driverStack" &&
          screen.index == 0 &&
          screen.routes[screen.index].index == 0 )
        || (
          screen.routeName === "ownerStack" &&
          screen.index == 0 &&
          screen.routes[screen.index].index == 0
        )
      )*Note:Please mention whatever condition you desire*
    ) {
      Alert.alert(
        "Are you sure",
        "You want to exit the App",
        [
          {
            text: "Cancel",
            onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
            style: "cancel"
          },
          { text: "OK", onPress: () =>{ BackHandler.exitApp() }}
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
      console.log("action",action,"state",state);
      return null;
    }
    else{
      return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
    }
  }
  else{
    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
  }
};
```

```
<PrimaryNavigation ref={nav => (this.primaryNavigator = nav)} />
```

Here the **PrimaryNavigation** is the **SwitchNavigator**

```
const PrimaryNavigation = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    splash: { screen: Splash },
    initialStack: { screen: InitialStack },
    stack2: { screen: Stack2 },
    stack3: { screen: Stack3 },

    DriverRegistrationStack: { screen: DriverRegistrationStack },
    OwnerRegistrationStack: { screen: OwnerRegistrationStack }
  },
  {
    initialRouteKey: "splash",
    headerMode: "none",
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to remove the Listener

```
useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            const onBackPress = () => {
                if (isSelectionModeEnabled()) {
                    disableSelectionMode(isOpen,bottomSheetRef);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            const subscription = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
            return () => subscription.remove();
        }, [isSelectionModeEnabled, disableSelectionMode, isOpen])
    );
```

Comment: Confirmed working.

Answer (score 0):

@Johncy is correct. The event listener will only be removed when your navigation stack is reset. This is the case if you are using React Native Navigation. The solution is to toggle if back press is available on each screen:

```
let isBackPressAvailable = false;

/**
 * Toggles back press
 * 
 * @param {*} enabled 
 */
export const toggleBackPress = (enabled = true) => {
  isBackPressAvailable = enabled;
}

/**
 * Handlers Android back button press
 *
 * @param appName
 *
 * @return {boolean}
 */
export const handleBackPress = () => {
  if(isBackPressAvailable){
    // DO STUFF HERE

    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

Setup the listener when your app is opened:

```
BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBackPress);
```

Then you can use `toggleBackPress(true/false)` to enable / disable custom behaviour for back press on each screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

for register

```
this.backhandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
  return true;
});
```

for remove (the best option is in the navigation not in `componentWillUnmount`)

```
this.backhandler.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react navigation you should try this.

```
    useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {

        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);

        return () =>
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
    }, [])
);

const backAction = () => {
    Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to go exit?", [
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            onPress: () => null,
            style: "cancel"
        },
        {text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()}
    ]);
    return true;
};
```